# FindElement doesn't find anything with Appium

Tags: c#, winforms, appium, appium-desktop

Using the following test method (simplified here for the purpose of the question, please ignore the design issues as this isn't the actual code)

```
[TestClass]
public class LoginTests
{
    protected static WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> session;

    [TestMethod]
    public void Login_WithValidCredentials_Logsin()
    {
        if (session == null)
        {
            var options = new AppiumOptions();
            options.AddAdditionalCapability("app", @"D:\myApp.exe");
            options.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
            session = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(WindowsApplicationDriverUrl), options);
            Assert.IsNotNull(session);

            session.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5);
        }

        //Arrange
        string username = "username";
        var txtUsername = session.FindElementByName("txtUsername");

        //Act
        //To be developed

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(username, txtUsername.Text);
    }
}
```

I can't find any element in the UI, the app launches correctly when the test is ran (having `WinAppDriver` running in the background) but no matter how I try to find the elements on the screen I always get the same error message

> "error":"no such element"
>
> "message":"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters."

### Update 1

Based on the first comment below, I used `inspect.exe` to confirm the name of the element on the screen that I'm trying to get and nop, I can't find it in the test.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you used inspect or UISpy to make sure you're looking for the correct names?

Comment: Have you tried running the code by adding **Wait** command??

Comment: There's a 1.5 seconds implicit wait in my code which I had increased to 10 seconds for testing. Also, I'm testing with the `Immediate Window` after the screen is loaded so, assuming the code is correct, elements should be found at that point. I think...